# Make a GET request after POST request is passed sucessfully with Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I am trying to make a file upload system on AWS based on laravel with ajax. I am talking about a resume parser system where i used the apilayer API to parse the CV from pdf to json.

I tried to make a file upload system where files are uploaded to aws (this works) and after i get the uploaded file url to send to API.

```
      public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'file' => 'required|mimes:doc,docx,pdf|max:2048',
        ]);

        $fileName = time() . '.' . $request->file->extension();
        $path = $request->file->storeAs('file', $fileName, 's3');
        CVupload::create(['name' => $fileName]);
        $urlcv = Storage::disk('s3')->url($path);
        return response()->json("$urlcv");
        }
}
```

Everything is ok, but when the API is executed from the below code i receive the error:

Client error: `POST https://api.apilayer.com/resume_parser/url?url=https://--.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/file/--` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:{"message":"You cannot consume this service"}

I see that the request is POST, and i have to make a GET REQUEST. Maybe its an error in Ajax Script?

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')

        }
    });
    $('#file-upload').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let formData = new FormData(this);
        $('#file-input-error').text('');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "{{ route('resume.store') }}",
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: (response) => {
                if (response) {
                    this.reset();
                    $("#showResponseArea span").html(response); //you will paste your response msg to the 
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: "{{ route('resume.api') }}",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: {
                            'url': response,
                        }
                    })
                }
            },
            error: function(response) {
                $('#file-input-error').text(response.responseJSON.message);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: As it is mentioned in the error that you have no permission to access the file, AWS restrict if you directly access the file you need to pass your key in the url which may not be the right thing, so you can save the file on server for temporary basis and once you upload the file you can then unlink the file.

Comment: But I have permission to access the file... Maybe the problem is that the request is POST, not get?

Comment: Then the response would be `405` method not allowed exception, can you explicitly open the aws url without key and check

Comment: I tried in postman to make the request as POST, not GET and the response was 403....

Comment: open that url in browser it will not open because you don't have permission to access aws assets without app key

Comment: https://isabelamazilu.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/file/1654858926.pdf  Here is a link example. In network at method i see that the request is GET but in message i see that is POST.. "Client error: `POST https://api.apilayer.com/resume_parser/url?url=https://isabelamazilu.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/file/1654858926.pdf` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:\n{\"message\":\"You cannot consume this service\"}\n"

Comment: Check out this link https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-troubleshoot-403-forbidden/ may give some help

Comment: But the file is uploaded to AWS. My problem is when i try to put the link to the APILAYER API. So i think that i have a problem with ajax code.